Has it been determined what "lewd, obscene, or offensive" clothing is?
It is in the news that Spirit Airlines ordered two women off a flight for wearing crop tops.  Their clothing seem completely normal to me.  The airline says "that its contract of carriage includes "certain clothing standards" for passengers.
I assume they are referring to section 4.3.1.g of their Contract of Carriage:

4.3.1. A guest shall not be permitted to board the aircraft or may be required to leave
an aircraft if that guest:
g. is barefoot or inadequately clothed, or whose clothing is lewd, obscene, or offensive in nature;

It seems like this is not a new type of clause, such that it must have come up before what the threshold for such categories are.  How is this language interpreted when these things come to court?

There is more detail in The Guardian. Apparently they had been wearing sweaters when boarding, but the air conditioning wasn't working so they took them off to prevent over-heating.

It sure seems like the flight attendants overreacted. The articles say they were wearing crop tops, which means shirts that are cut so the belly shows. I can easily imagine a protective parent objecting to a teenage daughter going out like this, but adult women wear them all the time in public with no outcry.

Unless the shirts were cut so short that parts of the breasts are visible. Many people may find that offensive. It's hard to know without seeing a picture. I expect the girls took selfies to use in court if necessary.

if people would stop dressing like haints while traeling by air we wouldn't have this problem.  My prediction is this is all an onlyfans ad.

Contracts are assessed objectively
That means that it doesn’t matter what Spirit or their passengers think the contract means, it matters what a hypothetical reasonable person would understand it to mean at the time of the formation of the contract.
From the footage, it is not clear why the passengers are being asked to leave the aircraft. It may be that they were asked to leave under 4.3.1.g, or it may be that they were requested to cover up, refused, and are being asked to leave under 4.3.1.c, failing to follow lawful instructions. Spirit only needs to engage one part of the clause to be entitled to eject them without breach of contract.
If the basis is 4.3.1.g, spirit will need to bring forward evidence that the passengers were “inadequately clothed, or whose clothing is lewd, obscene, or offensive in nature;”. The assessment is what a reasonable person in the circumstances would understand those terms to mean.
It’s important to realise that the “reasonable person” is a fiction - they are not a real person, nor are they are an average person. They are neither old nor young, they are of all ethnicities and none, they are neither rich nor poor, they are not easily offended but neither are they overly tolerant. Real people cannot testify as to what the reasonable person thinks because real people, no matter how reasonable they are, are not the reasonable person. The reasonable person is the embodiment of the relevant society.
What the reasonable person thinks in a particular case is a matter for the trier of fact - the jury or the judge in a judge only trial. And reasonable people can reasonably disagree about that so unless the decision-maker is manifestly unreasonable about it, such that no reasonable person could reach the decision they did, it’s not something that can be appealed.

Wouldn't the lawfulness of the instruction implicate the reason for issuing the instruction and possibly its reasonableness?  Suppose a passenger is wearing a three-piece business suit and, because of a lack of air conditioning, the plane's interior is 40 degrees Celsius (104 degrees Fahrenheit), and the crew instructs the passenger to put on the heavy overcoat that he just removed because business suits are offensive.  Would that be a lawful instruction?

@phoog sure. Don’t confuse lawful with reasonable. Instructions can be lawful and unreasonable - as the contract is written, refusing to obey one of those is grounds for ejection.

@phoog Note that the reasonable-person test covers only the determination that the passenger's clothes were offensive. It doesn't cover anything else that may flow from that determination.

I suggest that's a great theory and in practice, it's virtually impossible for such contracts to be assessed objectively.
